# Deploy a Django + SQL Server project using Apache

Tags: python, sql-server, django, apache

How can I deploy a Django project that uses SQL Server in Apache?

I created a project in Django and I want to put it in a Azure virtual machine and deploy it with apache, but I have some issues because SQL Server isn't supported for this framework, I have a database adapter like Django-Pyodbc, it works in my local but when I try to run it in a virtual machine than have Apache I get some errors, so what is the best way to do this?

Here is what the Apache error log shows:

> mod_wsgi (pid=41732): Failed to exec Python script file '/var/www/html/Agroweb/agroweb/wsgi.py'.
> (pid=41732): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/Agroweb/agroweb/wsgi.py'.
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/var/www/html/Agroweb/agroweb/wsgi.py", line 12, in 
> from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
> ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi
> caught SIGTERM, shutting down
> Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.6.8 Python/2.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
> Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'

Comment: Aside... you really should update your Apache server software. There have been no less than 38 CVE vulnerabilities addressed in the time between 2.4.41 and the current 2.4.57 release, ref: [Changelog Apache 2.4](https://www.apachelounge.com/Changelog-2.4.html).

Answer (score 0):

I found the error: Apache wasn´t reading the python3 version so I installed the following package in my virtual environment:

```
libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
```

This library helped me to read the python3 version instead of python2 and now my Django project is running in Apache.